# apt-mirror not syncing folders

Tags: packaging, apt, deb

I am trying to sync below files from a remote server to local machine using apt-mirror :

```
(myroot)

   1) Packages.gz 

   2) Too1 (contains deb file) 

       --- tool1.deb

   3) Tool2 (contains deb file)

            --- tool2.deb
```

In my local machine mirror.list, entry looks like this :

```
deb http://(remote-server-ip)/myroot
```

when I run the apt-mirror command, it downloads only Packages.gz and it ignores tool1 and tool2 folders from remote.
It looks like I need to maintain some standard folder structure on remote to allow apt-mirror to sync. 
Anyone, could help me out ?

Thanks a ton !!